# close wxpython windows when button clicked

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I have a wxpython gui that works fine as it is, when the "Component Defect" button is pressed(function compMonth), it opens a 2 windows, a gridForm and a pyplot window.  But if I run the the same button again without closing the gridFrom and pyplot windows, the program crashes.  Trying to add something to the button that would check to see if either of the windows are open and close them if they are.  Not really sure where to start,

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib
import csv
import datetime
import re
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter
import pysftp
import warnings
import os

import openpyxl
from pip._vendor.distlib.util import CSVWriter
import matplotlib


warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

filepath = os.path.join(os.path.expandvars("%userprofile%"),"Desktop")


powerfile = filepath+"\\Qual History.csv"
#print powerfile

today = datetime.date.today()
month = (today.month - 1)
year = today.year
month2 = month - 2
month3 = month - 3
if month == 1:
    month2 = 12
    month3 = 11
    year2 = year -1
    year3 = year2
elif month == 2:
    month2 = 1
    month3 = 12
    year2 = year
    year3 = year - 1
month = str(month)
year = str(year)
month2 = str(month2)
year2 = str(year2)
month3 = str(month3)
year3 = str(year3)
#print month, year, month3, year3
regex = re.compile(month +'/../'+year)
regex2 = re.compile(month +'/./'+year)
regex3 = re.compile(month2 +'/../'+year2)
regex4 = re.compile(month2 +'/./'+year2)
regex5 = re.compile(month3 +'/../'+year3)
regex6 = re.compile(month3 +'/./'+year3)
rootCause = ['COMPONENT DEFECT','EMC PROCESS DEFECT','METAL DEFECT','NFF','OTHER','VENDOR PROCESS DEFECT']

class gridForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Drill Down Data", size = (600,600), pos = wx.Point(1000,150))

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.myGrid = gridlib.Grid(panel)
        self.myGrid.CreateGrid(50, 4)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.myGrid, 1, wx.CENTER)
        panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)
#         
#     def SetCellValueWrapper(self):
#         self.myGrid.SetCellValue(0,0, "Failure")  #here is where ir starts
#         self.myGrid.SetCellValue(0,1, "Count")
#         self.myGrid.SetCellValue(0,3, "Percent Total")


class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        self.datarows = []

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "627 Data", size = (700,400), pos=wx.Point(600,0))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        self.monthButton = wx.Button(panel, pos = (250,5), id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Last Month")
        self.monthButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.lastMonth)
        self.month3Button = wx.Button(panel, pos = (350,5), id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Three Month")
        self.month3Button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.threeMonth)

        self.serialButton = wx.Button(panel, pos = (450,5), id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Get Serial Numbers")
        self.serialButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.serialNumbers)

        self.compButton = wx.Button(panel, pos = (250,50), id=wx.ID_ANY, label="COMPONENT DEFECT")
        self.compButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.compMonth)
        self.emcButton = wx.Button(panel, pos = (250,75), id=wx.ID_ANY, label="EMC PROCESS DEFECT")
        self.emcButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.compMonth)
        self.metalButton = wx.Button(panel, pos = (250,100), id=wx.ID_ANY, label="METAL DEFECT")
        self.metalButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.compMonth)
        self.nffButton = wx.Button(panel, pos = (250,125), id=wx.ID_ANY, label="NFF")
        self.nffButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.compMonth)
        self.otherButton = wx.Button(panel, pos = (250,150), id=wx.ID_ANY, label="OTHER")
        self.otherButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.compMonth)
        self.vendorButton = wx.Button(panel, pos = (250,175), id=wx.ID_ANY, label="VENDOR PROCESS DEFECT")
        self.vendorButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.compMonth)

        self.partLabel = wx.StaticText(panel,100, 'Part number', pos = (15,10))
        self.partText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos = (100,5), size = (100,-1))
        self.partText.SetInsertionPoint(0)
        self.compText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos = (100,50), size = (100,-1))
        # self.compText.SetInsertionPoint(0)
        self.emcText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos = (100,75), size = (100,-1))
        #self.emcText.SetInsertionPoint(0)
        self.metalText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos = (100,100), size = (100,-1))
        #self.metalText.SetInsertionPoint(0)
        self.nffText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos = (100,125), size = (100,-1))
        #self.nffText.SetInsertionPoint(0)
        self.otherText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos = (100,150), size = (100,-1))
        #self.otherText.SetInsertionPoint(0)
        self.vendorText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos = (100,175), size = (100,-1))
        #self.vendorText.SetInsertionPoint(0)
        # self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton, button)
#         self.myGrid = gridlib.Grid(panel)
#         self.myGrid.CreateGrid(20, 4)
#  
#         self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
#         self.sizer.Add(self.myGrid, 1, wx.CENTER)
#         panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)


    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def lastMonth(self, event):
        frame = gridForm()
        frame.Destroy()
        partNumber = self.partText.GetValue()
        if partNumber != "":
            csvfile = open(powerfile)
            datareader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
            compCount = 0
            emcCount = 0
            metalCount = 0
            nffCount = 0
            otherCount = 0
            vendorCount = 0
            self.datarows=[]
            for row in datareader:
                if re.match(regex,row[3]) or re.match(regex2,row[3]):
                    self.datarows.append(row)
                    if (row[1] == partNumber and  row[9] == 'COMPONENT DEFECT' ):
                        compCount += 1

                    elif (row[1] == partNumber and  row[9] == 'EMC PROCESS DEFECT' ):
                        emcCount += 1
                    elif (row[1] == partNumber and  row[9] == 'METAL DEFECT' ):
                        metalCount += 1
                    elif (row[1] == partNumber and  row[9] == 'NFF' ):
                        nffCount += 1
                    elif (row[1] == partNumber and  row[9] == 'OTHER' ):
                        otherCount += 1
                    elif (row[1] == partNumber and  row[9] == 'VENDOR PROCESS DEFECT' ):
                        vendorCount += 1
            self.compText.SetValue(str(compCount))
            self.emcText.SetValue(str(emcCount))
            self.metalText.SetValue(str(metalCount))
            self.nffText.SetValue(str(nffCount))
            self.otherText.SetValue(str(otherCount))
            self.vendorText.SetValue(str(vendorCount))


    def threeMonth(self, event):
        partNumber = self.partText.GetValue()
        if partNumber != "":
            csvfile = open(powerfile)
            datareader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
            compCount = 0
            emcCount = 0
            metalCount = 0
            nffCount = 0
            otherCount = 0
            vendorCount = 0
            self.datarows=[]
            for row in datareader:
                if re.match(regex,row[3]) or re.match(regex2,row[3]) or re.match(regex3,row[3]) or re.match(regex4,row[3]) or re.match(regex5,row[3]) or re.match(regex6,row[3]):
                    self.datarows.append(row)
                    if (row[1] == partNumber and  row[9] == 'COMPONENT DEFECT' ):
                        compCount += 1

                    elif (row[1] == partNumber and  row[9] == 'EMC PROCESS DEFECT' ):
                        emcCount += 1
                    elif (row[1] == partNumber and  row[9] == 'METAL DEFECT' ):
                        metalCount += 1
                    elif (row[1] == partNumber and  row[9] == 'NFF' ):
                        nffCount += 1
                    elif (row[1] == partNumber and  row[9] == 'OTHER' ):
                        otherCount += 1
                    elif (row[1] == partNumber and  row[9] == 'VENDOR PROCESS DEFECT' ):
                        vendorCount += 1
            self.compText.SetValue(str(compCount))
            self.emcText.SetValue(str(emcCount))
            self.metalText.SetValue(str(metalCount))
            self.nffText.SetValue(str(nffCount))
            self.otherText.SetValue(str(otherCount))
            self.vendorText.SetValue(str(vendorCount))



    def compMonth(self, event):

        ####this is where it should check for the windows and close them

        partNumber = self.partText.GetValue()
        csvfile = open(powerfile)
        datareader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
        compCount = 0
        compFails = []
        compFinal = {}
        performance = []
        serials =[]
#         
        for row in self.datarows:   
            if (row[1] == partNumber and  row[9] == 'COMPONENT DEFECT' ):
                compCount += 1
                serials.append(row[0])
                if row[7] == '':

                    compFails.append(row[13])
                else:
                    compFails.append(row[7])
        #print compFails
        c = Counter(compFails).items()
        c.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
        compFails.sort(key=Counter(compFails).get, reverse=True)
        #print compFails
        #print compFails
        for item in compFails:
            #print item
            compFinal[item] = compFails.count(item)
        #print compFinal
        count = len(compFinal)
        #print count
        frame = gridForm()

        frame.myGrid.SetCellValue(0,0, "Failure")
        frame.myGrid.SetCellValue(0,1, "Count")
        frame.myGrid.SetCellValue(0,2, "Percent Total")
        y=1
        x=0
        totalCount = sum(compFinal.values())
        for key in compFinal:
            percentage = "%.0f%%" % (100 * compFinal[key]/totalCount)

            frame.myGrid.SetCellValue(y,x,key)
            frame.myGrid.SetCellValue(y,(x + 1),str(compFinal[key]))
            frame.myGrid.SetCellValue(y,(x + 2), str(percentage))
            y += 1
            performance.append(compFinal[key])
        labels, values = zip(*c)
        indexes = np.arange(len(labels))


        plt.bar(indexes, values, align='center',)
        plt.xticks(indexes, labels, rotation = 'vertical')
        plt.ylabel('Number of Failures')
        plt.title('627 Pareto for ' + partNumber)

        frame.Show()
        plt.show()


    def serialNumbers(self, event):
        #plt.close(1)
        partNumber = self.partText.GetValue()
        csvfile = open(powerfile)
        datareader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
        compCount = 0
        serials =[]
#        
        for row in self.datarows:   
            if (row[1] == partNumber and  row[9] == 'COMPONENT DEFECT' ):
                compCount += 1
                serials.append(row[0])
        print serials
        writer = csv.writer(open(filepath+'\serials.csv', 'wb'))
        for word in serials:
            writer.writerow([word])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: have you tried catching the error?

Comment: no, not sure how to do that...

Comment: after __name__ == "__main__" add a try/except clause and print it to stdout or write it to a file or use the logging module

Comment: Running the program from the command line (terminal) will provide the error message.

Comment: I ran it from the command line, but no error was provided, the GUI just freezes and then it will go("Not Responding") and i will have to force close.

Comment: in the lastMonth method why do you create the frame and then immediately destroy it?

Comment: i was trying to see if I could destroy the frame if it was left open from the last time the button was pressed, it did nothing and has since been removed.

Comment: you're creating a new frame and then immediately destroying it. If you want to make a persistent reference call self.frame = ..., also frames are automatically destroyed when they are closed